# What happened to << when using ofstream without any filename pointed?

Tags: c++, ofstream

```
(1) default constructor
Constructs an ofstream object that is not associated with any file.
Internally, its ostream base constructor is passed a pointer to a newly constructed filebuf object (the internal file stream buffer).
```

what happened to << when using ofstream without any filename pointed?

```
ofstream  ofstream;
ofstream<<1<<endl;
```

where is the "1" go? is there any problems? I tried it, no issues. but I can't found any code clue for this, can anybody show the internal code explain for it?

Comment: I think it loads it into memory until you flush it. Try making a large amount of them and measure the memory change when you pass all of them a character

Answer (score 5):

**Nothing happens.**

> `[C++11: 27.9.1.1/3]:` In particular:
>
> - If the file is not open for reading the input sequence cannot be read.
> - If the file is not open for writing the output sequence cannot be written.
> - A joint file position is maintained for both the input sequence and the output sequence

The stream is closed, an error flag is set and the data is ignored.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    std::ofstream ofs;
    ofs << 1 << std::endl;

    std::cout << ofs.good() << std::endl;
}

// Output: 0
```

### [Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b70fcc9cd8bf0b93)

Answer (score 1):

The short version: the operations on the `ofstream` all fail, causing nothing to happen. The data that you write is lost and not stored anywhere, and the `failbit` will be set, causing the stream's `fail()` member function to return true.

The long version: when an `ofstream` is constructed without specifying a file, it default-constructs a `filebuf`. This creates a `filebuf` where `is_open` evaluates to `false`. As part of the stream insertion operation, the data to be written will need to be sent to the disk by calling `filebuf::overflow`, which, since `is_open` is false, will return `EOF`, causing the operation to fail.

Hope this helps!